# Is there a closed form formula for this function of two positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value, coupon-collector

Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers. Suppose there are $n$ cards in a deck, and you want to collect at least $k$ of each card. A store sells these cards, but here is the catch: It is random which card you will get. So, for example, if $n = 3$ and $k = 1$, then if you buy $4$ cards, it is possible you get two each of the first two cards, but none of the third card. If you keep buying enough cards, then with probability $1$ you will eventually get at least $k$ of each card. Let $f(n,k)$ be the expected value of the number of cards you have to buy to get at least $k$ of each of the $n$ cards. What is a closed-form formula, if there is any, for $f(n,k)$? Of course, if $n = 1$, then you just have to buy exactly $k$ cards. Also, I believe this problem has been studied for the special case of $k = 1$. I am generalizing it to the case of all positive integer $k$, not just $1$.

Comment: See [this MO site](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41935/how-to-solve-a-generalization-of-the-coupon-collectors-problem), this is exactly your problem.

Comment: The case $k=1$ is the “coupon collector problem.”  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: This is called the "double dixie cup problem".  See section 5, "Multiple collections with equal probability" in the survey article by Ferrante and Saltalamacchia [The Coupon Collector's Problem](https://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf) (pdf)